# (TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined)

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, state

I want to compare my redux store id with action payload id and update my redux store state using find method. Find method works just two times when I compare the same value at third time so find method gives me that error:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of undefined

```js
const initialState = {
  frontendCategory: [],
  backendCategory: [],
  devOpsCategory: [],
};

const reducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case actionTypes.ADDED_USER_TO_FRONTEND_CATEGORY:
      let updateddata = state.frontendCategory.find(data => data.id === action.payLoad.id);

      if (updateddata) {
        return [...state.frontendCategory];
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        frontendCategory: state.frontendCategory.concat(action.payLoad),
      };
  }
};

export const addedUserToFrontendCategory = (GithubUserId) => {
  return {
    type: actionTypes.ADDED_USER_TO_FRONTEND_CATEGORY,
    payLoad: {
      id: GithubUserId,
    },
  };
};
```

Comment: `if(updateddata){ return [...state.frontendCategory] }` are you just trying to check if id already exists in `frontendCategory`? because the variable name `updateddata` confuses me.

Comment: because if that's the case, I think you want to return the whole state `if(updateddata) { return state  }`

Comment: Yes Its works for me !! thankyou very much !!!

Answer (score 1):

When your updateddata becomes true you change the state from an object that contains frontendCategory to an array that contains properties from frontendCategory.

And when this happens, you got this error cause your state is now an array and does not have the frontendCategory as a property.

Maybe you should return always an object. Something like this:

```js
if (updateddata) {
        return state; // or return your business rule, but always an object contains frontendCategory as an array
      }

      return {
        ...state,
        frontendCategory: state.frontendCategory.concat(action.payLoad),
      };
```